# Using Tab Bar for Vertical Scrolling in React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I want to implement the Vertical Scrolling with changing tab view in react native.

Please check the demo in this URL:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Here the implementation is horizontal screen change, while I need to implement this vertical.

Comment: Do you want tabs also to be displayed vertical in View?

Comment: @KranthiKumarJulakanti no, Tabs will be horizontally placed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TouchableOpacity for tab buttons and use

```
react-navigation
```

package for navigation
and try to customize navigation animation using `transitionConfig` option

```js
var transitionConfig = () => ({
  transitionSpec: {
    duration: 300,
    easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
    timing: Animated.timing,
  },
  screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {
    const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps;
    const { index } = scene;

    const height = layout.initHeight;
    const width = layout.initWidth;
    const translateX = position.interpolate({
      inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
      outputRange: [height, 0, 0],
    });

    const opacity = position.interpolate({
      inputRange: [index - 1, index - 0.99, index],
      outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
    });

    return { opacity, transform: [{ translateX }] };
  },
});
```

Here the animation is a horizontal slide, you can change the transform to your required animation and by changing the transform object it is returning
and navigate to the required screen when clicked on the tab

Comment: How will I apply transitionConfig on the tab, Can you please share the complete code. It will help me understand better.

Comment: Sorry, this wont work for tab view, it is used to change navigation animation for screen